# problem-with-parenthesis-of-equation-label?

Tags: equations, xepersian, parenthesis

I'm new to LaTeX, trying to label an equation by this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{report}       
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{amsmath}       
    \begin{document}         
       \begin{align}
       \label{form1}
       A \oplus W \Rightarrow A_{W}
       \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

everything is OK, except parenthesis which show like this:

[image: like this].

I wonder why this happened and need help!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Oh my God, It is just the problem of rewriting my code here, and I should mention that I can not edit my question here.

Comment: @Narges: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I wonder why this happened but yesterday I send this question while I was sign out, and now this user is unregistered and no way to delete the question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @MartinSchröder thank you, I contact help center and try to solve the problem of two accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [similar question asked on ParsiLaTeX](http://qa.parsilatex.com/12207) so the solution is to load `amsmath` package before `xepersian` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{report}       
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xepersian}      
    \begin{document}         
       \begin{align}
       \label{form1}
       A \oplus W \Rightarrow A_{W}
       \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I asked it yesterday here, and cause no answer I ask it in ParsiLatex, Thanks for copying it here ;) I give you right answer point here

Comment: @Narges: I check  ParsiLaTeX every once in a while and rarely check this site; so it is best to ask your question on ParsiLaTeX if you seek my immediate answer.